# Cast response data to a Class containing a map

Tags: typescript

I receive some json data from the backend in this form. The field 'labels' is supposed to be a map of strings (that is how the backend handles it):

Received json data:

> 0: Object { labels: Object { group1: "developers" } name: "test1" }
>   1: Object { labels: Object { group2: "testers" } name: "test2" }

In my typescript code i have a class called Group. When I receive this response, I try to convert it to the Group class using

```
this.groups = <Group[]>data
```

My Problem is that the labels should be handled as a Map and not as an Object and this actually never happens using that line, so i am unable to set new keys and values. Which is the best way to achieve this? this is my code:

**service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectsService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }


  getGroups() {

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080' + '/groups' , { headers:headers })
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

**component**

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.groupsService.getGroups().subscribe(data => {

       this.groups = <Group[]>data
      console.log("Groups",this.groups)
    }
      , err => { console.log(err) })

  }

export class Group {
    name:string;
    users?:string[];
    labels?:Map<string, string>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map` is JavaScript class. JSON does not have such type, that's why `labels` is shown as `Object`. So you have two options:

- construct `Map` yourself from object `labels`
- change type of `labels` to `{ [label: string]: string }`, and use it as `Object`

Constructing map may look like this:

```
this.groups = (<any[]>data).map(group => {
   let labelsObject = group.labels;
   group.labels = new Map<string, string>();

   if (labelsObject) {
     Object.keys(labelsObject).forEach(key => group.labels.set(key, labelsObject[key]));
   }

   return <Group>group;
});
```